# How to set special folder permission on proFTPD?

Tags: debian, permissions, proftpd

On one of my servers, I have ProFTPD installed in Debian 7. I need special permission only for 2 specific folders. These are:

***append*** - user must be able to append data to an existing file

***rename*** - user must **not** be able to rename file if same exists

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand there are no special operations like append and rename that you can configure.

An **append** effectively is opening a file and then writing it with a different content (even if you only add to the file). You will need to have write privileges on that file.

A **rename** effectively is moving a file from an old location to another new location. You will need to have write privileges in that directory